# Sharepoint 2013 Site crashes after I publish a clickonce wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, sharepoint-2013, clickonce, ajaxcontroltoolkit

My sharepoint 2013 site was working perfectly. Once I publish a clickOnce wpf application, I get this error and the entire site crashes. The wpf application builds and is published successfully though.

**Error:**

> Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit,
>   Version=4.5.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\7286\web.config
>   Line: 572

**Note:**

- The proper AjaxControlToolkit.dll is found in the necessary bin folders and the right version tag is added in the web config.
- I am not using ajaxtoolkit controls anywhere in my wpf code (.Net framework : 4.5) . It is put in the config file because other sites under this web application uses it.

Any pointer to this issue will be quite helpful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint search assembly from the [Global Assembly Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6axd4fx6(v=vs.110).aspx), for this reason you must deploy the **AjaxControlToolkit** library into GAC or remove it from your project.

Comment: Thanks much Max :) your answer helped and now the site is working perfectly... I'll definitely up your vote once I reach the eligible reputation :D